# How can I optimize my Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) database for use with an API

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I created a MySQL Database into the Google Cloud Platform.

```
Machine type is db-n1-standard-2 with 2 vCPUs and 7.5 GB Memory. 
Network throughput (MB/s) is 500 of 2000
Storage type: SSD

Disk throughput (MB/s)
Read: 4.8
Write 4.8
IOPS
Read: 300
Write: 300

Availability: High availability

Database Flags:
max_connections: 500
```

I created a API with Laravel Lumen and let it work onto Google Cloud Platform into a App Engine

```
runtime: php72
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
    min_instances: 1
    max_instances: 20
    target_cpu_utilization: 0.7
    max_concurrent_requests: 80
    target_throughput_utilization: 0.8
```

If I send a request to my API with postman the first response needs 1123ms. The size of the response is 8.59 KB.

If I send the same request with loader.io with 250 clients over 1 minute,
the test aborted because it reached the error threshold.
79,5% error rate
avg resp = 9141 ms

min/max Responsetime is: 2081/10376
Response Counts success: 104
Response Counts timeout: 403

When I have a look at the MySQL Error Logging, I do have impossible much errors like this:

```
    2020-01-07 16:29:18.670 CET
2020-01-07T15:29:18.670275Z 1507 [Note] Aborted connection 1507 to db: 'mydatabasename' user: 'mydatabaseuser' host: 'cloudsqlproxy~172.217.35.158' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Does someone have an Idea, how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I've investigated a little about this error and found some useful guides on how to diagnose this types of errors at this [link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/) I believe that as a first step we would need to find the real cause of this message (this could be due to various reasons according to the link shared), some suggestions that I could notice repeating on other posts and on the same link that I shared before are the next:

- Check to make sure the value of max_allowed_packet is high enough ( this can be modified with flags in Cloud SQL).
- The client connected successfully but terminated improperly
- The client slept for longer than the defined wait_timeout or interactive_timeout seconds

What I would do is to go on and try tweaking the database flags as described on this [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags) on the google page and check how the behavior changes.

Please let us know if you find something useful when tweaking the instance.